# How to use Visual Basic ".vb" methods in a Django Project

Tags: python, .net, django, vb.net

In my actually job they're using an old Visual Basic WinForms apps and can't do a migration to another language.
The question is, i want to use the ".vb" files which exists and consume their methods whit python in a Django project. Sending and returning values and data from each one. How can i do this?

Connect a "Visual Basic" code with Django/Python

Comment: can you execute the VB script via `popen` or `call` and get the results?

Comment: @JonSG if it's a WinForms app, then it's not script.

Comment: Isn't, are just .vb files with code prepared with sql queries and methods, originally was planned to be a vb.net app